# Display category under correct header for custom coded forums

Tags: php, mysql, database, forum

I can't seem to find a way to link a category and a header using my custom coded forums.

Here is a picture of the categories table:

[image]

And a picture of the headers table:

[image]

Now both of those tables have a `FOREIGN KEY` link which is:

```
ALTER TABLE categories ADD FOREIGN KEY(cat_head) REFERENCES headers(head_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

A picture of my forums:

[image]

(notice how every category drops down under the "PrevailPots server" heading.

Comment: Improved formating and added pictures directly in the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly .

- 2 queries on both tables can do the trick .

> first query for retrieving details from the header table 
>   =>get the head_id

then

> second query on the category table
>   =>compare the cat_head with the head_id and retrieve the cat details .
>
> **Update**
>   I used the above Idea for my custom forum .
>   
>   example code

```
                $result1=queryMysql("SELECT * FROM headers"); //My custom function for query execution, returns the result    

            while($row1 =$result2->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC))
                {               
                        echo $row1['head_name'];
                $result2=queryMysql("SELECT * FROM categories WHERE cat_head=$row[head_id]");  // My custom function for query execution, returns the result    

                    while($row2=$result2->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC)){

                        echo $row2['cat_name'];
                        echo $row2['cat_description'];
                    }

                }
```

This is what I meant.

Today I would definitely try a JOIN operation something like  below.

```
         $result=queryMysql('SELECT * FROM headers LEFT JOIN categories ON head_id = cat_head');    //My custom function for query execution, returns the result    
             $new_head="";
             $pre_head="";
            while($row =$result->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC))
                {               
                        $new_head= $row['head_name'];

                        if($new_head!=$pre_head){
                          echo $new_head;
                        }
                         if($row['cat_name']!=null or $row['cat_description']!=null){
                          echo $row['cat_name'];
                          echo $row['cat_description'];
                        }
                        else {
                             echo "No categories yet";
                         }

                        $pre_head=$row['head_name'];
                }
```

> I think you got the idea now.

Comment: No luck trying to get the head_id and comparing it with the cat_head. Can you show me an example code of what you mean? I tried this:

CODE:
`$currentCategory = "";
if($currentCategory == "" || $currentCategory != $category_title){`
I also did a "full outer join" on both the tables to compare, no luck.

Comment: I think Left join is better in your case because ,every category will be under some headers right.

Comment: No the categories are assigned a header when being created in the forum admin panel. Which are FOREIN KEY linked to the cat_head and head_id.

Comment: Thank you very much! I had to modify that code a little but it worked just fine. Thank you again! :)